# Report parameters being displayed mutliple times

Tags: reporting-services

I want to have a summary table at the top of my report, showing which values were selected from the drop down list for each parameter, eg. date, ID etc.

The ID parameter drop down is actually a multi-select list with checkboxes, and the expression I've used to display this data in the summary table is as follows:

```
=Join(Parameters!ID.Value,",")
```

For the other parameters, I have the following in the expression:

```
=Parameters!Date.Value
```

When I run the report, the correct values are being displayed, but the 3 rows I have (from date, to date and ID) are being repeated multiple times - ie. the same number of times as rows returned via another dataset which takes in some of these parameters, if you know what I mean.

So I'm getting row 1, row 2, row 3, row 1, row 2 row 3, row 1......

Answer (score 0):

It seems that those expressions are placed into table detail cells. So they are executed for each row of that dataset.

You should put those expressions into table header cells.